# Forcing DIV to have the same margin on all sides

Tags: html, css

I've just spent 3 or 4 hours trying to understand how to get a "symmetric" DIV inside an HTML page that has to be not scrollable.

The DIV must have the same margins from the window on all sides and must contain an IMG whose size should scale according to the window size maintaining it's ratio.

At the [following link](http://jsfiddle.net/xjztbvgy/) you can find the best I've been able to do.

As you can see the DIV has the right margins on the left, top and right size but not on the bottom one! Why not?
Is there something wrong with the DIV style?

```
<div style="margin: 50px;">
```

I hope it's quite clear, thank you for your help! :)

Edit: since on JSFiddle it doesn't appear as it should be I've just uploaded an image about what I get on my browser:

[image]

Edit 2: this is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/k4t7kx1m/) to the last working solution, thank you all for your help, in particular to [dcardoso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486509/dcardoso). :)

Comment: The margins are the same to me, or am I missing something?

Comment: Could be padding on the body or the image not being `display:block` but it is hard to see the issue [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/xjztbvgy/1/)

Comment: Sorry, on JSFiddle the issue is not visible (don't know why there is the vertical scroll bar).
I've just uploaded a screenshot, so now it should be more clearer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add to your body and html tags (doesn't work in jsfiddle) and remove 'overflow: hidden':

```
position: relative;
height: 100%;
```

and to your div tag (remove 'margin:50px'):

```
box-sizing: border-box; /*This allows for the div padding to be included in the height and width size */
height: 100%;
padding:50px;
```

Comment: Thank you very much guy!!!
I didn't use your solution "as is" but I applied it to my page with some modifications and now it works perfectly!!!

The trick was using `box-sizing: border-box;` together with the `padding`, not the `margin` as I was doing.

Thank you again! :)

Comment: Glad I helped :) you should read this: [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts)... it is a good approach using it for all elements in a document.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read it for sure, I really need more knowledge about this topic!!!

Answer (score 2):

The page is getting cut because you are using `overflow: hidden;` for `html` and `body` .

when adding style tag inside jsfiddle style, it is not working. so scroll is visible.

Comment: You're right, I just deleted the "style" tag and now I get the same result as on my browser! :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, I think I get what you're saying. If the page is longer than your div the space on the bottom is greater than the 50px margin.

You have a couple of choices here, this is just one of many.

I'm using calc() to calculate the 100% width/height minus the 50px on each side.

```
     html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .maxSizeElement {
        width: calc(100vw - 100px);
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        margin: 50px;
    }

/* OR YOUR COULD USE...  */

    .maxSizeElement {
      position: absolute;
      width: 85vw;
      height: 85vh;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
       left: 0;
       bottom:0;
       margin:auto;
    }



    <body>
        <div>
            <img class="maxSizeElement" src="https://thelostdigit.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/wp_ss_20140507_0002.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you guy for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. :(

I've uploaded a screenshot to make the question clearer.

Comment: Ive updated my answer to work with vh/vw = viewport height/width

Comment: Bad support in older browsers, since calc function is not supported in many of them... source: [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: There are less than 10% to worry about with calc() but as an alternative you could use absolute position.

Comment: Your updated answer works! Thanks! :)

Do you know, by any chance, if is it possible to make the div to have the same size of the inner img?

I'm asking because I would need to put some labels inside that image...